# Using For loop with the Find function in Visual Basic Macro in Excel

Tags: excel, for-loop, find, vba

I am trying to figure out how to find all the numbers within a specific range (in this case between 1.900 and 2.100).

The code that I have written so far is able to find the numbers between 1.9 and 1.999 but it seems unable to find the numbers between 2.000 and 2.100. I checked the For loop to see if it was being completed and it is so it seems that something is wrong with the Find function.

Any help figuring this out would be appreciated. I have copied the code I've written below.

```
Sub FindPeaks()
With Worksheets(1).Range("b1:b500")
Dim i As Double
For i = 1.9 To 2.1 Step 0.001
    Set c = .Find(i, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            c.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Peak"
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
Next i

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just loop over the range and check the values?  Using Find() to look for specific numbers is not a good approach I think.

Comment: The answers provided will be a better way to achieve what you are trying to do, but (FWIW) the issue you are getting is due to the imprecision of decimal values in a binary system.  If you include a `Debug.Print i` statement directly after the `For` statement, you will see the effect of incrementing a value by `0.001`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and additional info! I've got the problem sorted now after the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer expands on the comment above to show a more efficient way of solving the problem

```
Sub FindPeaks()

Dim SRng as Range
Set SRng = Worksheets(1).Range("b1:b500")

For each cll in SRng
     If cll.value >= 1.9 and cll.value <= 2.1 Then
          cll.Offset(0,-1) = "Peak"
     End if
Next cll

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! This is very helpful and exactly what I was looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

Noting that the best way of addressing this task is not via VBA but worksheet formula it occurred to me that VBA can be used to write worksheet formulas. The code below should work faster than a loop.

```
Sub MarkPeaks()
    ' 26 Aug 2017

    Dim Rng As Range

    ' set the range to the cells where you want the result:
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C1:C500")

    With Rng
        ' write this formula: =IF(AND($B1>=1.9, $B1<=2.1),"Peak","")
        ' RC2 specifies the second column (meaning B)
        ' in the same row as the formula
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(RC2>=1.9, RC2<=2.1),""Peak"","""")"
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```